# Why does my windows in Windows act weird when moving them fast?

Tags: windows-7

I am not able to ask a proper question because I have no idea what the thing I am asking for is called. Perhaps it's tearing but I'm very unsure.

For example, if I grab a window and drag it around on the screen rapidly, the window will seem to be duplicated everywhere.

I don't know how to explain it so here is a video: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=ta4u8p%3E&s=8#.UvZ8tPl_v60

Comment: I see nothing strange about the behavior.  How much memory does your graphic card have?

Comment: It's feels strange to me. I don't think I have experienced it on other computers... I have a 280X with 4GB memory.

Comment: How much system memory do you have?

Comment: 6GB 1333MHz, quad core CPU

Comment: I watched the video and I simply did not notice anything weird to be honest.  Your CPU, GPU, and memory provide no reason screen tearing would even happen.

Comment: Its not weird it is normal. Do the same thing on different computer. It would be same. Nothing to worry about. Your graphic card memory n system memory is good enough. So dont worry

Answer (score 0):

My guess would just be screen lag, or just the way humans see things. I mean you're just jerking the window around, if you do that with anything else in real life, you see "double". I think that may be the case, but most likely just some screen lag. Doesnt seem like a problem though, since I cant think of any reason to ever do that....

Comment: It is absolutely not "human lag" or what I should call it. Because even if I just move the window ONCE, very fast from one edge of the screen to the other, the window will be very weird.

This is annoying and it doesn't happen on all computers.